# No wired or wireless networking available on Ubuntu 14.04 after update

Tags: 14.04, networking

I have using Ubuntu 14.04 for some time now but a strange thing happened yesterday. My laptop does not detect wifi or LAN connections. I did some search and ran some commands.
Here are the commands and outputs:

1. `sudo lshw -C network` output:

   ```
     *-network UNCLAIMED
              description: Network controller
              product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
              vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
              physical id: 0
              bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
              version: 01
              width: 64 bits
              clock: 33MHz
              capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
              configuration: latency=0
              resources: memory:c3400000-c340ffff
     *-network UNCLAIMED
              description: Ethernet controller
              product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
              vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
              physical id: 0
              bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
              version: 03
              width: 64 bits
              clock: 33MHz
              capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
              configuration: latency=0
              resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c1404000-c1404fff memory:c1400000-c1403fff memory:c1410000-c141ffff
   ```
2. `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` output:

   ```
   02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
       Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company U98Z062.12 802.11bgn Wireless Half-size Mini PCIe Card [103c:3040]
   03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
       Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:144a]
   7f:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers [8086:2c62] (rev 02)
   ```
3. `lspci -nnk` output:

   ```
   00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller [8086:0044] (rev 02)
       Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:144a]
       Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel
   00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port [8086:0045] (rev 02)
       Kernel driver in use: pcieport
   00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0046] (rev 02)
       Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:144a]
   00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller [8086:3b64] (rev 06)
       Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:144a]
   00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller [8086:3b3c] (rev 05)
       Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:144a]
       Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
   00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio [8086:3b56] (rev 05)
       Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:144a]
   00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:3b42] (rev 05)
       Kernel driver in use: pcieport
   00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:3b44] (rev 05)
       Kernel driver in use: pcieport
   00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller [8086:3b34] (rev 05)
       Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:144a]
       Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
   00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev a5)
   00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller [8086:3b09] (rev 05)
       Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:144a]
   00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:3b29] (rev 05)
       Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:144a]
       Kernel driver in use: ahci
   00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller [8086:3b30] (rev 05)
       Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:144a]
   00:1f.6 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem [8086:3b32] (rev 05)
       Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:144a]
   01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Madison [Mobility Radeon HD 5650/5750 / 6530M/6550M] [1002:68c1]
       Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Mobility Radeon HD 5650 [103c:144a]
   01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Redwood HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5000 Series] [1002:aa60]
       Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:144a]
   02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
       Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company U98Z062.12 802.11bgn Wireless Half-size Mini PCIe Card [103c:3040]
   03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
       Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:144a]
   7f:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers [8086:2c62] (rev 02)
       Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:144a]
   7f:00.1 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder [8086:2d01] (rev 02)
       Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:144a]
   7f:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 [8086:2d10] (rev 02)
       Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:144a]
   7f:02.1 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 [8086:2d11] (rev 02)
       Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:144a]
   7f:02.2 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved [8086:2d12] (rev 02)
       Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:144a]
   7f:02.3 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved [8086:2d13] (rev 02)

   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:144a]
   ```

Everything works fine when I boot 3.13.0-45-generic kernel. I do that by selecting it from **Advanced Options** from the GRUB menu. But when I boot into 3.13.0-46-generic (latest I have) the problem comes back.

Comment: what's the content of `cat /etc/network/interfaces`?  What happens if you do an `ethtool eth0`?

Comment: cat /etc/network/interfaces gives:
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

ethtool eth0 gives:
Settings for eth0:
Cannot get device settings: No such device
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: No such device
Cannot get message level: No such device
Cannot get link status: No such device
No data available

Comment: One another piece of info...everything works fine when i boot in 3.13.0-45-generic kernel. I do that by selecting it from advanced options from the GRUB. But when i boot into 3.13.0-46-generic (latest i have) the problem comes back.

Comment: What is the output of `ifconfig` on the 3.13.0-45 kernel?  Also, [edit] your answer instead of putting that crucial information in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Fabby. I have done that. The output of ifconfig in 3.13.0-45 kernel looks like:  lo Link encap:Local Loopback  inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0  inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host  UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1  RX packets:152 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0  TX packets:152 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  collisons:0 tzqueuelen:0  RX bytes:18687 (18.6 KB) TX bytes:18687 (18.6 KB)

Answer (score 1):

I kept using 3.13.0-45-generic kernel for a couple of days. In the meantime new kernel updates were downloaded by Software Updater and this fixed the problem.